# SQL calculation of percentage with group by with condition and sum of distinct items

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, percentage

I am dealing with the table as below:

[image]

Now my goal is to calculate with SQL the amount of distinct ID's by Zip Code and the percentage of ID's that is fraudulent grouped by the Zip Code. Important note: The same ID can occur several times and sometimes be a Fraud and sometimes not. If the ID is a fraud at least once, it counts as a Fraud. Only ID's that are constantly "True" are counted as non-fraudulent.

So the desired output should look like this:

[image]

What's the most efficient way to create my query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use following query. This is pseudo-sql, but I think you can get the point.

We group by `zip_code`, count distinct id using `count distinct` and finally count the percentage as a ratio of overall count of items in group and items which have fraud = 1.

```
SELECT 
  zip_code, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS number_distinct, 
  ((SUM(IF fraud = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100) AS percentage
FROM 
  table
GROUP BY 
  zip_code
```

Comment: Thanks! I have made a little error in the description. The Fraud column does not consist of 1 and 0 but of True and False. Would this change the query?

Comment: Just a little change, I modified the answer.

Comment: This yields the error: line 4:14: mismatched input 'fraud'. expecting: <expression> (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;

Answer (score 1):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select zip_code, count(*) as num_ids,
       avg(case when fraud = 'true' then 1.0 else 0 end) as fraud_ratio
from (select zip_code, id, count(*) as cnt,
             min(fraud) as fraud
      from t
      group by zip_code, id
     ) t
group by zip_code;
```

Note:  This uses the fact that as a string, `'true' < 'false'`.

Comment: Thank you. However, I get the error code: line 7:37: mismatched input '.'. expecting: '(', ',', 'cross', 'except', 'full', 'group', 'having', 'inner', 'intersect', 'join', 'left', 'limit', 'natural', 'order', 'right', 'tablesample', 'union', 'where', <eof> (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;

Comment: @Minfetli . . . The code as written works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e1f934efc54b912716ba5200e2a56e86.  It is Standard SQL and should work in any database.